# Quickly prune and create valid data combinations

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am really struggling with a problem where I need to "prune" down available scenarios to those that a user has defined as valid.  Below is a small example of the problem I am trying to solve in .Net (C#).  Given the levels / values shown below, the user could pick that there are only a few valid combinations, but if you imagine the levels below being 30-40 levels of data instead of the 5 I have shown, you could see my dilemma.  I could need to go through millions to billions of NOT VALID combinations to get to the Valid combinations.  There will be cases where all values in the level are applicable and some where only those combinations that the user has specified are.

Current Levels / Values of data:

[image]

Users have said that the valid combinations are:

```
*Notice all from level 4 are valid
Receiver -> Sony -> 500 -999 -> Retail
Receiver -> Sony -> 1000 - Up -> Retail
```

Results expected from the given 5 levels of information:

```
Receiver -> Sony -> 500-999 -> Open -Box -> Retail
Receiver -> Sony -> 500-999 -> New -> Retail
Receiver -> Sony -> 1000-Up -> Open -Box -> Retail
Receiver -> Sony -> 1000-Up -> New -> Retail
```

The things I have tried are performant with small sets, but if I was to have a lot of levels and big gaps in the combinations which wouldn't allow me to prune the valid combinations until I was deep into the levels, I am running into major performance problems.  I am obviously not tackling the problem incorrectly.

Any other views or suggestions on tackling the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Getting lots of negatives...is there a different stack forum where I could submit this?

Comment: Can you add the code you have so far?

Comment: Maybe you can expose your current solution, so we can understand more deeply your problem

Comment: Have you looked at how DNS works or Database indexes work? I believe your problem is similar to this. If I understand your problem correctly, as your customers make selections, other selections need to be excluded.

Comment: I will try to get some of my working code in (need to clean up a bit to make it clearer) and then move to programmers\

Comment: Take look at this answer. Hope this helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893349/how-to-efficiently-prune-data?rq=1

Comment: What's the form of your input?  Are you getting that as a string that you need to somehow parse, or do you already have an effective means of knowing which values from which levels are "valid", and only need to know how to combine them?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're able to parse your input into N different collections, each containing the valid values for a particular level, the problem is simply finding the Cartesian Product of those N collections.

Eric Lippert has [a blog post](http://ericlippert.com/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/) in which he walks through the creation of a solution to get the Cartesian Product of a number of sequences unknown at compile time.  The code, taken from the end of that post, is:

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences) 
{ 
  IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() }; 
  return sequences.Aggregate( 
    emptyProduct, 
    (accumulator, sequence) => 
      from accseq in accumulator 
      from item in sequence 
      select accseq.Concat(new[] {item})); 
}
```

Using this code with your example input:

```
var validValues = new string[][]{
    new string[] {"Receiver"},
    new string[]  {"Sony"},
    new string[]  {"500 -999","1000 - Up"},
    new string[]  {"Open -Box","New "},
    new string[]  {"Retail"},
};

foreach(var combination in  validValues.CartesianProduct())
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", combination));
```

Provides the output:

```
Receiver Sony 500 -999 Open -Box Retail
Receiver Sony 500 -999 New  Retail
Receiver Sony 1000 - Up Open -Box Retail
Receiver Sony 1000 - Up New  Retail
```

Comment: Thanks Servy that is a great start.....I will modify / start wtih that and read Eric's blog posting

Comment: @scarpacci Well, there really isn't anything more that can be provided unless you [answer my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150153/quickly-prune-and-create-valid-data-combinations#comment26585015_18150153) as to the specifics of how the input is provided.  I don't want to even consider what all would need to be done in trying to parse/process it without know if it's even a problem to start with, or what the specifics of it might be.

Comment: I will provide more details today that will shed some light on your questions.